# convert list<baseclass> in List<derivedclass>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

class product from entity framework

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductBarcode { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

created a derived class

```
public class ProductPlus : Product
{
    public bool Restock { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateSold { get; set; }        
}
```

I got data from the DB in a List

```
List<Product> lstProduct = (from p in entity.Product select p).ToList();
```

I've tried:

```
List<ProductPlus> lstProductPlus = lstProduct.Cast<ProductPlus>().ToList();
```

or

```
List<ProductPlus> lstProductPlus = lstProduct.ConvertAll(x => (ProductPlus)x).ToList();
```

Gives:  Unable to cast object of type 'product' to type 'ProductPlus'.

```
var lstProductPlus = lstProduct.Select(item => item as ProductPlus).ToList();
var lstProductPlus = lstProduct.Select(item => new ProductPlus()).ToList();
```

Gives : Exact the number of records as in lstProduct, but all empty

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Not all `product`s are `ProductPlus`es, so you can't updcast.  Where do the `Resock` and `DateSold` values come from?

Comment: They will be inserted after this by rules and calculations

Comment: The `OfType<T>` extension method is the one to use here, not `Cast<T>`.

Comment: @DStanley No, cast will fail if you can't cast *ANY* item in the collection. `OfType` will return instances in the collection that *could be* cast--in other words, all ProductPlus instances in his collection.

Comment: @DStanley First, there isn't any `ProductType` in OP's question. Pay attention.  Second, `ProductPlus` extends `Product`, and therefore can be contained within the collection.  So, `new Product[]{ new ProductPlus() }.OfType<ProductPlus>()` would yield one result.  This, `new Product[]{ new ProductPlus(), new Product() }.Cast<ProductPlus>()`, would fail.

Comment: @DStanley Wrong.  Product cannot be cast to ProductPlus but a Product may be a ProductPlus.  Product has no knowledge of ProductPlus.   ProductPlus can be cast to Product because all ProductPlus are Product.

Comment: @Frisbee True in general but I'm making the reasonable assumption that `entity.product` contains `Product` objects and _not_ this custom `ProductPlus` extension.

Comment: @DStanley Look, you can make all the baseless assumptions you want, but you aren't making an ass of me.  You can continue to make an ass out of yourself--that's fine. I think it's pretty clear that he's mixing the two types in the collection. Otherwise, what's he doing with this question?  Never mind, don't bother answering that. I'm done crapping in OP's inbox.  Good day to you, sir.

Comment: @Will, Thanx for you comment, but would you be more professional in you answer instead the "ass" calls to D. Stanley. Disagree is oke, but the way you tell it, ain't, no matter what your history is.

Comment: @Frisbee, Thanx for the uppercase correction.

Comment: @Dinand That's a reference to the old saying, "when you ASSUME you make an ASS out of U and ME."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you inherit the `Product` class? I think you want to add 2 more fields to the `Product` class, right?

Because the auto-generated class is a `partial` class, instead of inheriting the `Product` class as you did, just add one more file to the partial class like this:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public bool Restock { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateSold { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Maybe OP is using inheritance for a reason?  Don't use inheritance is not a valid answer.

Comment: I don't think so. Just in case this is an XY problem.

Comment: Thanx man, You saw the reason of the problem and the right solution.
Crazy enough sometimes I use partitial, but blind to see this simple using.

Answer (score 2):

Add a constructor to `ProductPlus` that takes `Product` as an argument.

```
public class ProductPlus
{
    public ProductPlus() { }

    public ProductPlus(Product p){
        SomeProduct = p;
    }

    public Product SomeProduct { get; set; }
    public bool Restock { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateSold { get; set; }        
}
```

Then in your code call:

```
var lstProduct = lstProduct.Select(item => new ProductPlus(item));
```

Comment: Sorry Ben,Also tried, but gives: ProductPlus does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments. Above the class takes no arguments

Comment: I don't think modify the auto-generated class is a good idea. Your modification will lose when the class is regenerated.

Comment: @Dinand I've updated the example to include product as a constructor argument for ProductPlus.

Comment: You took away the ProductPlus : Product

Comment: @Frisbee I added it as a property of ProductPlus, since product is an auto generated class.

Comment: So you still took away inheritance.

Comment: @Frisbee It's really up to the OP to decide if he wants to inherit from an auto generated class.  Personally, I wouldn't.  The answer I posted illustrated the problem and provided a solution.

Comment: Uh, derived class, ProductPlus : Product.  I see indication that is what he wants to do.

Comment: @Frisbee A derived class isn't the only solution.  OP can decided if he wants to proceed with a derived class or some other method.

Comment: @Ben M. Thanx for the answer Ben M.
Yes works great. While the answer of Frisbee solves my problem the nicest way, I'm happy with your solution. It solves also in other conditions some problems. I voted you up for this

Comment: @Dinand Glad to help.  If you ever plan on caching your 'Product' entities, this pattern will allow you to make changes to 'ProductPlus' specific properties without worrying about messing with an underlying cached referenced type.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
 List<ProductPlus> lstProductPlus = lstProduct.ConvertAll(x => new ProductPlus()
 {
   CompanyID = x.CompanyID,
   ProductID = x.ProductID,
   ProductBarcode = x.ProductBarcode
 }).ToList()
```

Comment: I'm familair with you answer, but if something in the DB changes,...... So it works, but is the worses solution of all. I wanne have if clean and dynamic. But Thanx for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every ProductPlus is a Product
You can cast a ProductPlus to a Product

But not every Product is a ProductPlus
You cannot cast a Product to a ProductPlus unless it already is a ProductPlus

Consider a class

```
public class ProductDesign : Product
{
    public DateTime? ProjectedCompletion date { get; set; }        
}
```

Tested, just try it out

```
{
    // ...
    public void TestInheritance()
    {
        try
        {
            Product p01 = new Product() { ProductBarcode = "p01" };
            ProductPlus pp01 = new ProductPlus() { ProductBarcode = "pp01" };
            Product p02 = (ProductPlus)pp01;
            //ProductPlus pp02 = (ProductPlus)p01; // throws a cast error

            List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
            productList.Add(p01);
            productList.Add(pp01);

            //List<ProductPlus> productPlusList = productList.ConvertAll(x => (ProductPlus)x).ToList(); // throws a cast error 

            List<ProductPlus> productPlusList = productList.Where(x => x is ProductPlus).ToList().ConvertAll(x => (ProductPlus)x).ToList();
            foreach (ProductPlus p in productPlusList)   
                Debug.WriteLine(p.ProductBarcode);  // 1 item 

            List<ProductPlus> productPlusMajicList = productList.Select(x => new ProductPlus(x)).ToList();
            foreach (ProductPlus p in productPlusMajicList)
                Debug.WriteLine(p.ProductBarcode);   // majic 2 tiems
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }


    }
}
public partial class Product
{
    public int? ProductID { get; set; }
    public string  ProductBarcode { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyID { get; set; }
    public Product() { }
    public Product(Product p)
    {
        ProductID = p.ProductID;
        ProductBarcode = p.ProductBarcode;
        CompanyID = p.CompanyID;
    }
}

public class ProductPlus : Product
{
    public bool? Restock { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateSold { get; set; }
    public ProductPlus() { }
    public ProductPlus(Product p) : base(p) { }
}
```